# SSL certificate for Tor

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, https, ssl, certificate

I have setup a Tor Hidden Service, and have the .onion domain. I wish to setup HTTPS.

As I am using a self signed cert when a user visits my site they get a warning, which is extremely off putting.

I have seen many Tor sites using HTTPS which do not get any warnings.

- Where can I get a certificate which allows .onion addresses? I tried using free Letsencrypt but they do not allow .onion domains yet.

I know HTTPS is not really necessary due to the amount of security already used on Tor, however I do like the extra protection.

Thank you!

Comment: https://blog.digicert.com/anonymous-facebook-via-tor/ might be relevant to your interests.

Comment: That's a huge company paying thousands. I don't see how regular darknet marets etc... manage to get them?!

Comment: They probably don't.

Comment: @canonizingironize They do.

Comment: Certs were discussed in a previous official Tor blog post: https://blog.torproject.org/blog/facebook-hidden-services-and-https-certs. DigiCert currently seems the only way to go. Do you have a pointer to a regular .onion site that uses HTTPS?

Comment: spoke to the user on IRC and apparently on rechecking they couldn't find any, they were just sure they'd seen one. There's also [CertSimple who will also do .onion](https://certsimple.com/help/tor-support), apparently. This [mailinglist thread](https://lists.torproject.org/pipermail/tor-project/2016-May/000335.html) covers some of the examples of sites with EV TLS Certs.

Comment: Raise your voice at trac.torproject.org.
https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/ticket/21767

Comment: Are these answers still correct at the end of 2020?

Answer (score 2):

At the moment the only way to get a trusted SSL certificate for a .onion domain is to buy an EV (extended validation) certificate.

For more info see: https://www.digicert.com/blog/ordering-a-onion-certificate-from-digicert/